# Как добавить в объект значение из переменной

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict"
let base = {};
let user = "Вася"
base.user = 1;
for (let key in base) {
    alert("Имя: " + key)
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы в `alert` был `Вася`? Надо сделать, чтобы работало даже, если не знать `user` заранее.

Comment: `base[user] = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Вы делает выборку по ключам, а хотите показать значения. Значит нужно получить значения:

```
base["user"] = user;
for (let key in base) {
    alert("Имя: " + base[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use strict"
let base = {};
base["Вася"] = 1;
for (let key in base) {
  console.log("Имя: " + key)
}
```